# Gradle test includes by file name

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, build.gradle

My unit test files has a suffix *Test.java.
There are some base classes that the tests classes extend, but the base classes have no tests, and they do not end with *Test.java.

I'm trying to use gradle test dsl to run the unit test classes, and exclude the base classes. My code looks like this:

```
test {
    includes ['**/*Test.java']
    useJUnit {
        excludeCategories 'com.category.to.ignore' // a category I have for test that I currently exclude
    }
}
```

Still, there are some base classes that get triggered and fail.
Is this the right way to include specific test files?

Comment: Could you please try `includes ['**/*Test.class']` - `class` instead of `java`?

Comment: @Opal I tried, same result

Comment: Are the base classes abstract BTW?

Comment: I don't know if the default for inclusion/exclusion is an ant pattern . Sorry for guesswork, but what about `*Test`?

Comment: @Opal The class is not abstract. @ mkobit tried, but gradle still tries to run that class as test.

Comment: @TidharKleinOrbach, could you please provide an example that reproduces the problem? I've created an example project but can't reproduce it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a huge and complex project so I can't share it as is. I will try to build something similar that will reproduce the issue.